# Remove imageView sublayer from TableViewCell

Tags: ios, core-data, ios5, calayer

When I have an image I insert sublayer with CAGradientLayer,

```
...
layer.name = @"Gradient";
[cell.imageView.layer insertSublayer:layer atIndex:0];
```

and when there is no image for ImageView I need to remove this sublayer.
I tried different ways with no success. The last I tried was

```
for (CALayer *layer in cell.imageView.layer.sublayers) {
    if ([layer.name isEqualToString:@"Gradient"]) {
        [layer removeFromSuperlayer];
    }

}
```

but it gives me an error:

```
CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  *** Collection <CALayerArray: 0xc1502e0> was mutated while being enumerated. with userInfo (null)
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The exception is thrown because you are changing the contents of the `sublayers` array while enumerating it with foreach loop. This is not something special to layers, a similar exception is thrown when you add/remove objects while enumerating any NSMutableArray.

You have various options to solve this issue

**Solution 1:** Stop enumerating as soon as you modify the array.

```
for (CALayer *layer in cell.imageView.layer.sublayers) {
    if ([layer.name isEqualToString:@"Gradient"]) {
        [layer removeFromSuperlayer];
        break;
    }
}
```

**Solution 2:** Do not enumerate the real array, instead use its copy.

```
NSArray* sublayers = [NSArray arrayWithArray:cell.imageView.layer.sublayers];
for (CALayer *layer in sublayers) {
    if ([layer.name isEqualToString:@"Gradient"]) {
        [layer removeFromSuperlayer];
    }
}
```

**Solution 3:** Use key value coding to keep a reference to the gradient layer.

Set it after inserting:

```
[cell.imageView.layer insertSublayer:layer atIndex:0];
[cell.imageView.layer setValue:layer forKey:@"GradientLayer"];
```

Retrieve and remove it

```
CALayer* layer = [cell.imageView.layer valueForKey:@"GradientLayer"];
[layer removeFromSuperlayer];
[cell.imageView.layer setValue:nil forKey:@"GradientLayer"];
```

Comment: Thank you guys :) I tried No.3 first, it didn't worked for me,
but No.2 works like a charm.

Comment: solution 2 is best. Worked like a charm :) Thanks a lot

Comment: Solution-2 is awesome and perfectly working. Thanks a lot, it saved my whole day.